# Phonegap build failed with no resource foudn for @mipmap/icon

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

Since a week my phonegap build is failing and could not figure out what is making the build failed.
Did a bit of research and tried few options like adding a mipmap folder but still the build fails.

/project/build/intermediates/manifests/full/release/AndroidManifest.xml:59: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@mipmap/icon').

My config.xml file is below:

```
 <content src="index.html" />

    <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="70000" />
    <platform name="ios" >
        <preference name="orientation" value="all" />
        <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="android" >
        <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
       <!-- <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="google-services.json" /> -->
    </platform>

    <preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
  <preference name="SplashScreen"               value="splash" />
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen"       value="true" />
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay"          value="1000" />
  <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio"  value="true" />
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreen"           value="false"/>



<plugin spec="https://github.com/rodrigo-martinezd/cordova-dialog-gps.git#f110314" />
<plugin spec="https://github.com/cuisineje/cordova-plugin-dreams-inappbrowser.git#fafbc28" />
<plugin spec="https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-cordova.git#011f82b" />
<plugin name="com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk" spec="3.5.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-permissions" spec="1.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.7" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="2.4.3" /> <!-- Had issue with 3.0.0 as it required cordova 6.3.0 -->
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-googlemaps" spec="2.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" spec="3.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="1.3.4" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy" spec="2.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="4.1.0" source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-toast" spec="2.6.0" />
<plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" spec="3.4.2" />
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="1.5.3" />
<plugin name="uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator" spec="4.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid" source="npm" />
<!--
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" source="npm" spec="1.5.3" />
    <gap:plugin name="com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk" source="npm"  />


    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm"/>



    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" spec="2.4.3"/>
   <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-permissions" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy" source="npm"  spec="2.2.0" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-toast" source="npm" spec="2.6.0" />
    <plugin name="uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator" source="npm" />


    <gap:plugin spec="https://github.com/rodrigo-martinezd/cordova-dialog-gps.git" source="git" />
    <gap:plugin spec="https://github.com/cuisineje/cordova-plugin-dreams-inappbrowser.git" source="git" />

    <gap:plugin spec="https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-cordova.git" source="git" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" spec="3.0.0" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" source="npm" spec="3.4.2" />
-->

    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-googlemaps"  source="npm" spec="2.1" >
       <param name="API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" value="AIzaSyC25RhPHKmvQTz7OzprugQyzWssMlvWKHA" />
       <param name="API_KEY_FOR_IOS" value="AIzaSyC25RhPHKmvQTz7OzprugQyzWssMlvWKHA" />
    </gap:plugin>

    <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker" />
    </feature>

    <feature name="SplashScreen">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
    </feature>

    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="deployment-target" value="7.0" />
    <!-- ios preferences -->
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />

    <access origin="*" />
    <access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />

    <gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">
        <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" />
        <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        </application>
    </gap:config-file>


    <platform name="ios">
        <icon height="57" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="50" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
      <icon height="120" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120"/>
      <icon height="180" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="29" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
    </platform>

    <icon platform="android" qualifier="ldpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
    <icon platform="android" qualifier="mdpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
    <icon platform="android" qualifier="hdpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
    <icon platform="android" qualifier="xhdpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
    <icon platform="android" qualifier="xxhdpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-152-xxhdpi.png" />
    <icon platform="android" qualifier="xxxhdpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-192-xxxhdpi.png" />

    <splash platform="ios" src="splash.png" />

    <splash src="splash.png" />
```

Comment: Simply there is no icon in `res/mipmap/icon` that's why error occured.

Comment: Until now I never had this error.. and why now? I don't get it..

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it by adding the following tags and changed the file names.
And specified the cli version too look like this

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.4.0" />
```

icon tags

```
<platform name="android">
      <icon density="ldpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
</platform>
```

Comment: I found something wierd.. when I upload my payload zip to phonegap.com, it throws me this mipmap error but when I do from another PC , it compiles.. Any guess ?